# Success Handler for Multiple Spring Security SAML RelyingPartyRegistrations

Tags: spring-security, saml

I am using Spring Security 5.5.3 to hit two separate SAML Identity Providers (IDP) (similar to, say, Google and Facebook, but not OAuth).

So, in my Security configuration, I define the two `RelyingPartyRegistration` beans:

```java
public RelyingPartyRegistration site1RelyingPartyRegistration() {
    RelyingPartyRegistration registration = RelyingPartyRegistration.withRegistrationId("site1")
        // rest of configuration
        .build();
    return registration;
}

public RelyingPartyRegistration site2RelyingPartyRegistration() {
    RelyingPartyRegistration registration = RelyingPartyRegistration.withRegistrationId("site2")
        // rest of configuration
        .build();
    return registration;
}

    @Bean
    public RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository() throws Exception {
        Collection<RelyingPartyRegistration> registrations = Collections.unmodifiableList(
                Arrays.asList(
                        site1RelyingPartyRegistration(),
                        site2elyingPartyRegistration())
        );

        InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository repository = new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(registrations);

        return repository;
    }
```

Then I define my SuccessHandler:

```java
public class MySuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException{

        // need to determine whether the success came from site1 or site2
    }
}
```

My question is, since I can authenticate from more than one Identity Provider, how can I find out which site it was? The only idea I have is to pull the entire `<samlp:Response>` from the `Saml2AuthenticationToken` and parse it to an XML document to get a single String attribute.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Security 5.6, it's included in the `Authentication`:

```java
Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal = 
        (Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
String registrationId = principal.getRelyingPartyRegistrationId();
```

Before Spring Security 5.6, you can customize the `Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal` in the authentication provider:

```java
OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider provider = 
        new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();
provider.setResponseAuthenticationConverter((params) -> {
    Response response = params.getResponse();
    Saml2AuthenticationToken token = params.getToken();
    RelyingPartyRegistration registration = token.getRelyingPartyRegistration();
    String registrationId = registration.getRegistrationId();
    // ... create custom authentication that contains the registration id
});
```